Did Jesus remain a servant after his ascension to heaven as shown in the disciples prayer in Acts 4:24-30?
The expression "your servant Jesus" was twice used in the disciples prayer addressed to the God of Jesus after his ascension. Why did the disciples see Jesus as God's servant after his ascension to heaven if he was a servant only while on earth?
In addition, the Hebrew Bible expression "the God of Abraham, the God of Isaac and the God of Jacob" used in Acts 3:13 call Jesus his (God's) servant. This was stated after his ascension to heaven.
Is Jesus still God's servant after his ascension to
heaven?

Acts 4-24 ASV: And they, when they heard it, lifted up their voice to God with one accord, and said, O Lord, ]thou that didst make the heaven and the earth and the sea, and all that in them is: 25 who by the Holy Spirit, by the mouth of our father David thy servant, didst say,
Why did the Gentiles rage,
And the peoples imagine vain things?
26 The kings of the earth set themselves in array,
And the rulers were gathered together,
Against the Lord, and against his Anointed:
27 for of a truth in this city against thy holy Servant Jesus, whom thou didst anoint, both Herod and Pontius Pilate, with the Gentiles and the peoples of Israel, were gathered together, 28 to do whatsoever thy hand and thy council foreordained to come to pass. 29 And now, Lord, look upon their threatenings: and grant unto thy servants to speak thy word with all boldness, 30 while thou stretchest forth thy hand to heal; and that signs and wonders may be done through the name of thy holy Servant Jesus.


Acts 3:13 ASV: The God of Abraham, and of Isaac, and of Jacob, the God of our fathers, hath glorified his Servant Jesus; whom ye delivered up, and denied before the face of Pilate, when he had determined to release him.


Is this another "gotcha" question?

Perhaps a more fundamental question should be answered first: why do some translations have the word "servant" rather than "son" or "child".

@RevelationLad. The term " Lord God" is never used to refer to Jesus. The verse containing the prayer makes it clear that the disciples prayer to the Lord God show that they call Jesus as "His servant.". So did Jesus remain God's servant after his ascension to heaven?

@RevelationLad. Thank you for the correction. It is "Sovereign Lord" Acts 4::24..This term is never used to refer to Jesus?

Many are called Lord & servant - David being called both - A Lord to the people as respect and a servant to the One Almighty GOD - Jesus would fall in the same category

The operative word here is παῖς, παιδός for which BDAG offers three meanings:

a younger person, normally below the age of puberty with focus on age rather than social status, boy, youth, eg, Matt 17:18, Luke 2:43, 9:42, Acts 20:12, etc
one's own immediate offspring, child, eg, John 4:51, Luke 18:51, 54, etc
one who is committed in total obedience to another, slave, servant, eg, Luke 7:7, 15:26, 12:45, Matt 8:6, 8, 13, 14:2, Luke 1:54, 69, Acts 4:25.  Of Christ specifically: Matt 12:18, Acts 3:13, 26, 4:27, 30.

It is this final meaning that is used in Acts of Jesus who is referred to several times in the book of Acts as a "servant":

Acts 3:13 - The God of Abraham, Isaac, and Jacob, the God of our fathers, has glorified His servant Jesus. You handed Him over and rejected Him before Pilate, even though he had decided to release Him.
Acts 3;26 - When God raised up His Servant, He sent Him first to you to bless you by turning each of you from your wicked ways.”
Acts 4:27 - In fact, this is the very city where Herod and Pontius Pilate conspired with the Gentiles and the people of Israel against Your holy servant Jesus, whom You anointed.
Acts 4:30 - as You stretch out Your hand to heal and perform signs and wonders through the name of Your holy servant Jesus.”

This idea of Jesus being a servant is consistent with the prophecies of Isaiah that the coming Messiah would be a servant to all: Isa 42:1, 48:20, 52;13, 53:11.  Indeed, Matthew quotes Isa 42:1-4 about Jesus being the fulfilment of Isaiah's prophecies about the Messiah being a servant:

Matt 12:18 - Here is My Servant, whom I have chosen, My beloved,
in whom My soul delights. I will put My Spirit on Him, and He will
proclaim justice to the nations.

It is also consistent with Jesus' own teaching about Himself:

Matt 20:28 - just as the Son of Man did not come to be served, but
to serve, and to give His life as a ransom for many.”

I will not speculate about the OP's reasons for asking this question.  However, the idea that Messiah was a servant to all shows His true greatness which we are to emulate (1 Cor 6:13).  Put another way, Jesus being a servant to all humanity does not make Him less than human but greater than human as Heb 1 is at pains to point out.
That is, far from demeaning Jesus, in the kingdom of heaven, the greatest is the servant of all.  This is confirmed in Phil 2:9-11 where, following Jesus ultimate humiliation as a servant, we are told that:

Therefore God exalted Him to the highest place and gave Him the name
above all names, that at the name of Jesus every knee should bow, in
heaven and on earth and under the earth, and every tongue confess that
Jesus Christ is Lord, to the glory of God the Father.

I also pause to note that this verse directly quotes Isa 45:23 as applying to YHWH (Jehovah) and thus affirms that Jesus is Jehovah of the OT.

This answer would benefit from addressing the specific term used in Acts, and speaking to the difference between the different types of “servants” as the terms are used in the NT and LXX. The term in Acts is understood by some as servant, and by some as child and by some as son.

@RevelationLad - good and fair point.  I will update accordingly.

for clarification is Jesus still a 'Man' servant / 'God' servant /  or humans are the servant of 'God'?                   as to your OT quotes don’t stand up to scrutiny - How can Jesus (God) be exalted (exalted to what if he is already God, Supreme God)?

@anothertheory - with this question again???  Look at the sequence in Phil 2:  Jesus was God (V5, 6) and then humbled Himself during the incarnation (v7, 8) and then exalted back to the being the king of the universe in V9-11.  Jesus remained with the human body after the resurrection Luke 24:39.

@Dottard Philippians 2:6: "Have this mind among yourselves, which is yours in Christ Jesus, who, though he was in the form of God, did not count equality with God a thing to be grasped." (Not God - form of God' & not equal - unless you go to a distorted translation as the KJ version).  Luke cant even get his story straight and your position would be contradictory to 1 Peter 3:18  He was put to death in the flesh but made alive in the spirit..  At present is Jesus a human body / God body / spiritual body?

@anothertheory - I am not going to argue with you except to suggest that your quoted version is inaccurate (having just read the Greek) - "form" here means the very essence of God.  But you will not subscribe to what the Greek says.

@anothertheory - your translation of V5 is also misleading - the Greek does not contain "yours", or, "among", nor, "yourselves".  V6 does not have "though", etc, etc.

@Dottard I didn’t mention V5, V6 yes ‘though’ may not be in there - 'form' does appear to be there, but essence still would not imply God himself ('very essence' please share the word you are using to come to that).  I won’t respond regarding my disagreement but would be interested to know - what is Jesus at the moment - human body  / God body (whatever that may be as God is not a man) / spiritual body?

@anothertheory - ask a question and I will answer.

@Dottard not asking for a detailed explanation - simply what do you think Jesus is now & what Greek word you are using for 'very essence'

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

By the way regarding, Phil 2:9-11, I don't get your point. In Isaiah it says every knee will bow and every tongue confess to God. In Phil 2 doesn't say that every knee will bow and every tongue confess to Jesus.

@Austin - that is the point - Phil 2:9-11 confirms that the "God" in Isa 45:23 is Jesus.

@Dottard, how, when Jesus isn't the one they confess to? They *'confess that Jesus'... *They don't 'confess to Jesus...'

@Austin - again, that is the point - everyone agrees that Jesus is Lord and God according to isa 45;23.  The operative verb here is ἐξομολογέω = to acknowledge, admit.  Confess is a bit misleading.

@Dottard, I'm sorry if you are mislead by the word confess, which to me means to acknowledge or admit, but if you prefer these words the case is the same: In Isaiah they admit to God. In Philippians they don't 'admit to Jesus', they 'admit that Jesus' This is a big difference. I can admit that 2 equals 1+1 , but that doesn't mean that I admit to the number 2 anything.

@Austin - I think you are tripping over a Greek translation (the LXX in the NT) of the Hebrew - it is the same thing.

@Dottard, I think you misapprehend that Philippians is a quotation of the LXX instead of a riff of it and thus misinterpret it. What the LXX says and what Philippians say are quite different. It's nothing like a simple substitution of Jesus for God. It doesn't even use the word ἐξομολογέω.

Answer
Jesus did not remain a servant after His ascension to the Father in heaven. The idea is not shown anywhere in the Scripture.
Explanation
A true Christian should not bother about what other “experts” say about Lord Jesus because Jesus and His true apostles have said and witnessed more than enough about Jesus’s personality.
How Jesus viewed Himself
Jesus viewed Himself as the Lord above His servants.

“You call Me Teacher and Lord, and you are right, for so I am”
(John 13:13).


“Remember the word that I said to you: A servant (apostle or prophet)
is not greater than his Lord (Jesus); if they persecuted Me (the
Lord), they will also persecute you (the servant)” (John 15:20).


“But do not you be called Rabbi, for One is your Leader, the
Christ, and you are all brothers” (Mat 23:8).


“If anyone serves Me, let him follow Me; and where I am, there
My servant will also be” (John 12:26).


“for the Son of Man (Jesus) is Lord even of the Sabbath” (Mat
12:8).


“Blessed that servant (apostles and prophets), whom his Lord
(Jesus), having come (Jesus is the One to come), will find doing
so” (Mat 24:46).


“and the servant does not remain in the house—throughout the age,
the Son remains—throughout the age” (John 8:35).


“and behold, One greater than Solomon is here” (Mat 12:42).


“and behold, One greater than Jonah is here” (verse 41).

The above are some of what Jesus witnessed about Himself. But Jesus also said:

“I am the One witnessing concerning Myself, and He who sent Me, the
Father, witnesses concerning Me” (John 8:18).

Let us listen to the Father’s witness just once (there are several):

“While he was yet speaking, behold, a radiant cloud overshadowed them.
And, behold, a voice out of the cloud saying, This is My Son, the
Beloved, in whom I have been delighting; hear Him” (Mat 17:5).

How the Holy Apostles Viewed Jesus
All the apostles had a very high concept of Jesus and worshipped Him.

“And "Moses" truly "was faithful in all his house" as a ministering
servant, for a testimony of the things having been spoken; but Christ as Son (not servant) over His house, whose house we are”
(Heb 3:5-6).


“In many ways and in various ways of old, God spoke to the fathers in
the prophets; in these last days He spoke to us in the Son” (Heb
1:1-2).

Jesus also always distinguished Himself (Son of God) from the prophets and apostles (servants of God) as is evident in His parable of the Lord of the vineyard (Luke 20:9-18).

“The Word which He sent to the sons of Israel, preaching the gospel of
peace through Jesus Christ, this One is Lord (not servant) of
all” (Acts 10:36).


“but to us there is one God (Elohim), the Father, of whom are all
things, and we for Him, and one Lord (Yahweh) Jesus Christ,
through whom are all things, and we by Him” (1 Cor 8:6).

[This is a very powerful Scripture because it says there is only "one” Lord and that is Jesus Christ. Does it mean God the Father cannot be Lord? Yet, the Scripture calls God the Father Lord many times. If so, then Jesus is God because the Scripture calls Jesus God.]
Quoting Isaiah 45:23 where Yahweh says that every knee shall bow before Him and every tongue shall swear Yahweh, Apostle Paul states:

“that at the name of Jesus "every knee should bow," of heavenly ones,
and earthly ones, and ones under the earth, and "every tongue should
confess" that Jesus Christ is "Lord" (that is, Jesus is Yahweh,
not servant), to the glory of God the Father” (Phlp 2:10-11).

This is why Apostle John witnessed Apostle Thomas confessing the resurrected Jesus as:

“And Thomas answered and said to Him, My Lord (Yahweh)
and my God (Elohim)!“ (John 20:28).

So, Jesus Christ is Lord and God or Yahweh Elohim, not servant.
Man Jesus, Servant?
The only place where I found (ready to be corrected) Jesus referred as servant is the famous Philippians 2:7:

“Christ Jesus, who subsisting in the form of God, thought it not
robbery to be equal with God, but emptied Himself, taking the form of
a slave (doulos/servant), having become in the likeness of men and
being found in fashion as a man, He humbled Himself, having become
obedient until death, even the death of a cross” (Phlp 2:5-8).

There is more here than what meets the eyes.
Originally Christ Jesus “existed” in the form of God; He was equal in nature with God the Father;
But later “took” the form of a slave/servant; became in the likeness of men; found in fashion as a man.
Let us concentrate more on this verse.
Jesus “took” the “form (morphe) of a slave” or servant. Now, by a slave/servant, the Scripture means a human being. So when Jesus became a human being, He was 100% a human being in nature. There is no doubt about it.
If so, when Jesus originally existed in the “form (morphe) of God” He was definitely more than 100% God by nature. This is why He was “equal with God” the Father in nature.
Like Father like Son.
Hence, Jesus demanded an equal reverence due to Him that is due to God the Father:

“The Father wants all people to honor the Son as much as they
honor him. When anyone refuses to honor the Son, that is the same as
refusing to honor the Father who sent him” (John 5:23).

The Truth
The simple truth is that Jesus Christ is God in nature as much as His Father is God in nature. However, just as a father will be higher in authority, God the Father is greater in authority than the Son (John 14:28); otherwise the titles will be meaningless!
Thus we see that Jesus is equal to God the Father “in nature” but God the Father is greater “in authority” than the Son.
A human father is greater in authority in the family. This does not mean that the son is any less human. So when God the Father is greater in authority, that does not mean Jesus is any less God. “The Word was God”.
Conclusion
Jesus originally existed as Yahweh Elohim (Phlip 2:6 and John 20:28) but emptied Himself and became a human being or servant for a short time (verses 7-8). God was able to die because He “emptied” His glory and power (verse 8). But God the Father restored Him back to His original position (verse 9). So Jesus is Yahweh Elohim (verses 10-11).
As God, He is no longer a servant.
So we read:

“The kings of the earth stood up, and the rulers were assembled on the
same day against the Lord, yea, against His Christ. For truly both
Herod and Pontius Pilate, with the nations and the peoples of Israel,
were assembled against Your holy child (pais) Jesus, whom You
anointed…….And now, Lord, look upon their threatenings and give to
Your slaves (doulos) to speak Your Word with all boldness, in the
extending of Your hand for healing and miraculous signs and wonders to
happen through the name of Your holy child (pais) Jesus” (Acts
4:26-27,29-30).


a brief as possible response - 1) Doulos – appears to be ‘of a servant’ – ‘paida’ often means servant as in Acts.  ‘Pais’ also appears to mean servant Matt 12:18.  So not sure its as clear as you say.   2) Isaiah 42:1 Behold my servant ….. (if you believe this relates to Jesus) & IS 49:3.  Jesus is also called a Prophet which is a servant.  3) Phil 2:7 – form would mean like God but not God and most translatiosn have ‘did not consider to be equal with God’ or similar Yet we have KJV who want to misrepresent and say ‘thought it not robbery to be equal with God’

Ok, in brief: 1) “doulos” cannot be translated as a “child”; pais/paida can be. 2) Jesus always distinguished Himself as Son, different from the servants. However, I don’t have any problem in accepting Him “prophetically” as servant as per Gal 4:1. 3) Phil 2:7 – if Jesus is like God but not God, then He is like a human but not a human which is inaccurate. It goes both ways. He existed as God but emptied Himself of His God nature and took a human nature. This meaning is inescapable.

And this is the greatness of Christ Paul wants to highlight; that though Christ originally was, in nature, God, equal, in nature, to God the Father, He did not consider this equality something to be held on but readily emptied Himself and took the nature of a human being even to the point of death. This is the agape love of God.

1)'doulos' I didn’t say anything about 'child' 2) Is 42:1 says 'servant' regardless of any distinction otherwise you have to accept its a contradiction 3) Phil2:7 'form' & not 'equal' to God, clearly implies he is not God regardless of how you may wish to interpret it 3) Phil 2:9 'exalted' how can God need to be exalted then he must be a lesser God not equal.  See more on Phil 2   https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/97275/33268

1)I just highlighted the difference. 2) I have already agreed to this though there is a difference between Son servant and other servants. 3a) Phlp 2:7 I didn’t interpret. I simply cited Paul explaining the fact. Jesus took the “form” of a mortal man but originally He existed in the “form” of God. If He became a real human being, then He really was God. This truth is like a double edged sword. It cuts across both sides. You cannot say that it is sharp on one side but blunt on the other side! 3b) Phlp 2:9 Simple. He needed to be ‘exalted’ because before He ‘emptied’ His God-nature.

Multiple Usage of WordsThe ancient languages were know to use words that could be translated in multiple ways. For example, the Latin word ago could be translated as "do, act, drive (a horse), depending on the accompanying words in the sentences.
So also in Greek, and this word in particular. As noted before, this word used in Acts, could mean a young son, an off-spring, or one committed to serve (obey) another. How it is interpreted---and translated into English---is determined by the context of the writings in which it is contained.
King James TranslatorsThe dozens of translators of the King James Bible were unified in translating this word in Acts as Son and Child:

The God of Abraham...hath glorified His Son Jesus, whom ye delivered up...(Acts 3:13)
Unto you first God, having raised up His Son Jesus, sent Him to bless you...(3:26)
The kings of the earth stood up, and the rulers were gathered together against the Lord, and against His Christ, For of a truth against Thy holy Child Jesus, whom thou hast anointed, both Herod and Pontius Pilate...were gathered together...(4:26-27; Compare Luke 2:11-17)
Lord...by stretching forth your hand to heal; and that signs and wonders may be done by the name of thy holy child Jesus. (4:30)

Moot QuestionThe version used by the OP did use "servant" in their translation, from whence the posed dilemma comes. However the KJV, which many believers have use for centuries, eliminated this confusion, and makes this posting moot! The Son is eternally the Son in the Godhead (Triunity), along with the Father and Spirit.
The translators were no doubt influenced by the reoccurrence of Son in other scriptures such as in the book of Hebrews:

God who at various times and in divers manners spake in time past unto the fathers***, has in these last days spoken unto us by His Son... (1:2-3)


But unto the Son He says, Thy throne, O God, is for ever and ever; a scepter of righteousness is the scepter of thy Kingdom. (1:8)


Seeing then that we have a great high priest that is passed into the heavens, Jesus the Son of God, let us hold fast our profession. (4:14)


Though He were a Son, yet He learned obedience by things which He suffered. (5:8)


...but the word of the oath, which was since the Law, maketh the Son, who is consecrated for evermore. (7:28)

Keeping in mind that neither men nor angels are to be worshipped (Revelation 22:8-9), consider the summary in the book of Philippians:

Let this mind be in you, which was also in Christ Jesus: Who, being in the form of God, thought it not robbery to be equal with God, but made Himself of no reputation, and took upon him the form of a servant, and was made in the likeness of men.And being found in fashion as a man, He humbled himself, and became obedient unto death, even the death of the cross.Wherefore God also hath highly exalted Him, and given Him, a name which is above every name, that at the Name of Jesus every knee should bow, of things in heaven, and things in earth, and things under the earth, and that everyone should confess that Jesus Christ is Lord, to the glory of the Father! (Philippians 2:5-11)

There is no doubt that Jesus served the will of the Father on earth---and now serves as High Priest Intercessor, if we may use the word serve (Hebrews 7:25)---but Jesus, the Son, is no less God than the Father and Spirit...for all eternity!

"The ancient languages were know to use words that could be translated in multiple ways. For example, the Latin word ago could be translated as "do, act, drive (a horse), depending on the accompanying words in the sentences." I think the perspective is misplaced. There were many different types of servants so there were different words to express differences. A child sold into slavery was a doulos. A son who chose to be a servant would better be described as pais. This might be true even in a situation where the slave owner bought the child.

@Revelation Lad - However, in this OP,  the word translated differently is one word, not several words as per your examples of different words for the idea of a "servant".  So my perspective is accurate.

My examples? I just quoted from what you wrote.  If it’s wrong maybe you should edit the answer.

@ Revelation Lad - The Latin word "ago" is just one word.
